# Create fuction in pgplsql has error in if condition

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, procedure

I am trying to create function in postgres

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cms_inventory_proc() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN 
IF NEW.permanent = 'YES' THEN 
INSERT INTO cms_inventory(id, version, scheme_id, register_num, cms_reference, sensor_id) 
    VALUES (NEW.id, 0, NEW.scheme_id, NEW.register_num, NEW.cms_reference, NEW.sensor_id);
END IF;   
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 9: IF NEW.permanent ='YES' THEN**

*While it is working in online compiler*

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that? Maybe that tool doesn't understand dollar quoted strings

Comment: The function and the error don't match. The error has `IF NEW.permanent LIKE '%yes%'` whereas the function has `IF NEW.permanent = 'YES'`. You need to reconcile that.